# Laravel ManyToMany to same Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Okay guys, i am trying to rephrase my question. Lets see how try 2 goes :)

I have a artisan command to calculate the total earnings for every user.

Every day a User gets earnings assigned. But sometime, how should I describe it, he made the earnings with stuff from another user.

And thats the assert_user_id column. If a user (user 2) made earnings with stuff from another user (user 1), these earnings should be added to the earnings of user 1 in this scenario.

```
id, user_id, earnings, asset_user_id
 1,   1,        15,       null
 2,   1,        43,       null
 3,   1,        49,       null
 4,   2,        32,       1
 5,   2,        25,       1
 6,   2,        12,       null
```

(In this case, user 2 is making almost all of his money with content from user 1... not very nice of him, thats why the money)

The Artisan commands gets all users. and goes through them with a foreach.

inside the foreach we call a method on the user model

`return $this->sum('earnings');`

**remember, I am inside the collection of user 1.**

And now I want to sum all earnings where asset_user_id = 1. The problem, the collection persist only the rows of user 1.

Now the question:

How can i access all other rows from inside a collection of a user. Yeha i could just do User:all() within my function in my model. But i don't think this would be SOLID code. So how do i do it the right way?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about mysql, not laravel. Do you already have an sql query you want to convert? Or are you asking how to do this by iterating over the collection?

Comment: How to query it is easy. Thats not a problem. But Yes, i want to do it over the creator model / collection.
I am getting all creators with a foreach and then get total1 over the collection. Now i am locking for a easy way to get total2 over the collection.

Comment: Rephrase your question, so we know, what is your expected result. How does Eloquent model, and many-to-many relationship goes with it?

Answer (score 0):

What you will probably want to do is iterate over the collection with `foreach` and get the sums yourself.

```
$results = Result::all();

$sum1 = 0;
$sum2 = 0;

foreach($results as $result) {
    if($result->creator_id == 1 && $result->status = 'r') {
        $sum1 += (int)$result->earnings;
    }

    if($result->asset_creator_id == 1 && $result->status = 'r') {
        $sum2 += (int)$result->earnings;
    }
}
```

There is also a `sum` method in the `Collection` class which might be a bit easier.  Just send it a callback which returns the value you are looking for.  We would have to do it twice though, once for each sum you are looking for.

```
$sum1 = $results->sum(function($result)
{
    if($result->creator_id == '1' && $result->status = 'r') {
        return $result->earnings;
    }
});

$sum2 = $results->sum(function($result)
{
    if($result->asset_creator_id == '1' && $result->status = 'r') {
        return $result->earnings;
    }
});

echo "Creator Earnings: ".$sum1;
echo "Asset Creator Earnings: ".$sum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting, counting, summing over collection would be always worse solution than doing it with db query.

Anyway your question is messy, you ask for `status=r`, write total for `status=f`, so just a guess, to show you how you can accomplish that with Eloquent features:

```
public function getEarningsForAssetCreator($id)
{
  return $this->where('asset_creator_id', $id)
           ->where('status', 'f')
           ->sum('earnings');
}
```

Comment: haha :) yeha my qustion is a bit messy, i am not sure how i can explain my problem the best. But Your answer didnt answered my question.
The problem is, i get all creators. 
So i am in the collection of creator 1. But the data i want is in the collection of Creator 2 and is not in the Collection of creator 2.
So i was thinking maybe to add a Relation to the same table but another model and the foreign keys are different. instead of id -> creator_id maybe id -> asset_creator_id. Or something like this.

Comment: OK, forget about those collection for now and tell me what is expected result?

Comment: The expected result, get all rows with asset_creator_id = 1 from inside the collection of creator 1, which only contains rows of creator 1. But asset_creator_id = 1 rows are only in rows of other creators.

Comment: If I get you right, then you want to sum earnings for user 1 from rows with `user_id = 1` or `asset_user_id = 1` - correct?

Comment: See how bad i am at asking questions :D I make everything work complicated then it is. But yeha thats basically my question. But with the addition that i am in the collection of user 1

Comment: But really, why don't you sum it in the db query? There is a way to do it using tweaked relationships, so you can call it like `$user->earningsSum` and even eager load that for a collection of users.

Comment: because i need separated. One function in the model to sum where user_id = 1 and one for asset_user_id = 1.
How dose the relation has to look like? I am in the collection of user 1. And i want to access all rows where asset_user_id = 1 but user_id != 1, if in my collection i only have user_id = 1 entires. Because i get all users and foreach them. So i only have the data of one user.